# Python: string test not evaluating

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I'm trying to do what should be simple string comparison, but I can't get it to work:

```py
class Bonk:
  def __init__(self, thing):
    self.thing = thing

  def test(self):
    if self.thing == 'flarn':
      return 'you have flarn'
    return 'you have nothing'

bonk1 = Bonk('glurm')
bonk2 = Bonk('flarn')

bonk1.test()
bonk2.test()
```

This returns **nothing**.  I've tried this too:

```py
def test(self):
  if self.thing in ['flarn']:
    ...
```

and that doesn't work either.

I've tried double quotes, assigning 'flarn' to a variable and then testing against the variable, adding a comma at the end of the list test.  I tried passing it in as a variable instead... but nothing is working.

What am I missing?

Comment: So uh... by "returns nothing", do you mean there's no output? Because `bonk1.test()` definitely _returns_ a value, but you'd need to _do_ something with it like `print(bonk1.test())`

Comment: yeah.  this didn't occur to me; my presumption was that the `return` would output the string much like it does with `__str__` and `__repr__`.  you are correct, though.  and thank you.  :)

Comment: `__str__` and `__repr__` do not automatically print anything. You might be confused by a feature of your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistaken how to write OOP classes slightly, though a good attempt since you are on the right track!

Here is a working implementation of what you're trying to achieve:

```py
class Bonk:
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
  
    def test(self):
        if (self.thing == 'flarn'):
            return 'you have flarn'
        return 'you have nothing'

bonk1 = Bonk('glurm')
bonk2 = Bonk('flarn')

print(bonk1.test()) # you have nothing
print(bonk2.test()) # you have flarn
```

#### Explanation

When creating a Python Object, the `__init__` is a customization function that is called in order to assign properties to the object.

```py
def __init__(self, thing): # Bonk object constructor with property
    self.thing = thing # Set the property for this object
```

You can then create additional functions for each object, such as `test()`, which takes `self` as the first parameter that will reference the object itself when invoked.

```py
def test(self):
    if (self.thing == 'flarn'): # Check the saved property of this object
        return 'you have flarn'
    return 'you have nothing'
```

**Relevant Documentation:** https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: ...so i have to `print()` it?  *sigh*  coming from a JS/PHP core, how Python handles strings is doing my head in...  what i did instead was replace the `return`s with `print`s and added a `return True/False` respectively, but i fully understand (now) why i had to `print` the method (as it were...).  SMH.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the comments and the other suggested solution, you can also do this and avoid the use of another function **def test()** by just implementing that function check within the initializer. Lesser lines of code and it does the job.

```
class Bonk:
   def __init__(self, thing):
     self.thing = thing
     if self.thing == 'flarn':
       print('you have flarn')
     else:
       print('you have nothing')

bonk1 = Bonk('glurm')
bank2 = Bonk('flarn')

=== output ===
you have nothing
you have flarn
```

Comment: nope.  sorry.  don't let the method name mislead you; it still need to be a method.